# Email fields comparison validation in Woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, woocommerce, checkout

I have a custom field called `gift` and I am now trying to validate that against the `billing_email` field. In other words, if the customer fills in the gift field and it is the same email as the billing email, an error should be shown when clicking "complete order" button.

It does not work. Any ideas why? Here's the code.

```
// verify that billing email and gift email are not the same
function billing_email_and_gift_validation( $posted ) {
$checkout = WC()->checkout;
if ( strcmp( $posted['billing_email'] == $posted['gift'] )) {
wc_add_notice( __( 'To send as gift, you cannot send it to yourself. That\'s the point of a gift, is it not?', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' ); } }
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'billing_email_and_gift_validation', 10, 2 );
```

Thank you all if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have merged this validation with the gift validation from this question code you have made before, so you will remove it from your actual code as this function handle both of them:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'gift_custom_field_validation', 20, 2 );
function gift_custom_field_validation( $data, $errors ) {
    // Validating that "Gift" is not empty when selected
    if( isset($_POST['gift_msg']) && isset($_POST['gift']) && empty($_POST['gift']) )
        $errors->add( 'gift', __( "You've chosen to send this as a gift, but did not submit a recipient email address.", "woocommerce" ) );

    // Validating that "Gift" imputed email is different from billing email
    if ( isset($_POST['gift']) && $data['billing_email'] === $_POST['gift'] ) {
        $errors->add( 'gift', __( "To send as gift, you cannot send it to yourself. That's the point of a gift, isn't it?", "woocommerce" ) );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.